# Redirecting output to $null in PowerShell, but ensuring the variable remains set

Tags: powershell

I have some code:

```
$foo = someFunction
```

This outputs a warning message which I want to redirect to $null:

```
$foo = someFunction > $null
```

The problem is that when I do this, while successfully supressing the warning message, it also has the negative side-effect of NOT populating $foo with the result of the function.

How do I redirect the warning to $null, but still keep $foo populated?

Also, how do you redirect both standard output and standard error to null? (In Linux, it's `2>&1`.)

Comment: What produces the warning message? If you are the author of `someFunction`, you might change it appropriately.

Comment: Actually, in Bourne Shell (Linux), it's `2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null`; The redirect you've shown redirects stderr to the same place as stdout -- which may be `/dev/null`, or may be a regular file.

Answer (score 210):

I'd prefer this way to redirect standard output (native PowerShell)...

```
($foo = someFunction) | out-null
```

But this works too:

```
($foo = someFunction) > $null
```

To redirect just standard error after defining $foo with result of "someFunction", do

```
($foo = someFunction) 2> $null
```

This is effectively the same as mentioned above.

Or to redirect any standard error messages from "someFunction" and then defining $foo with the result:

```
$foo = (someFunction 2> $null)
```

To redirect both you have a few options:

```
2>&1>$null
2>&1 | out-null
```

---

**ADDENDUM:**

Please note that (Windows) powershell has many more streams than a linux based OS. Here's the [list from MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.3):

[image]

Thus you can redirect *all* streams using the wildcard with `*>$null`, and you can also use a file instead of `$null`.

Comment: This solution worked for me after I wrapped the statements in {curly braces} instead of (parenthesis).  I may be using a newer PS version.

Comment: And if we are creating a background job, we need to quite the job'ing itself: `{ myCommandWithAnyOutput & } | Out-Null`

Answer (score 16):

This should work.

```
 $foo = someFunction 2>$null
```

Answer (score 15):

If it's errors you want to hide you can do it like this

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"; #This will hide errors
$someObject.SomeFunction();
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"; #Turning errors back on
```

Answer (score 6):

Warning messages should be written using the `Write-Warning` cmdlet, which allows the warning messages to be suppressed with the `-WarningAction` parameter or the `$WarningPreference` automatic variable. A function needs to use `CmdletBinding` to implement this feature.

```
function WarningTest {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($n)

    Write-Warning "This is a warning message for: $n."
    "Parameter n = $n"
}

$a = WarningTest 'test one' -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

# To turn off warnings for multiple commads,
# use the WarningPreference variable
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$b = WarningTest 'test two'
$c = WarningTest 'test three'
# Turn messages back on.
$WarningPreference = 'Continue'
$c = WarningTest 'test four'
```

To make it shorter at the command prompt, you can use `-wa 0`:

```
PS> WarningTest 'parameter alias test' -wa 0
```

Write-Error, Write-Verbose and Write-Debug offer similar functionality for their corresponding types of messages.

Answer (score 1):

using a function:

```
function run_command ($command)
{
    invoke-expression "$command *>$null"
    return $_
}

if (!(run_command "dir *.txt"))
{
    if (!(run_command "dir *.doc"))
    {
        run_command "dir *.*"
    }
}
```

or if you like one-liners:

```
function run_command ($command) { invoke-expression "$command  "|out-null; return $_ }

if (!(run_command "dir *.txt")) { if (!(run_command "dir *.doc")) { run_command "dir *.*" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had to shut up powershell on a Linux host, this wasn't that obvious to figure out. After back and forth I found out that wrapping a command in `$( )` and adding a explicit redirection after the wrapper works.

Anything else I tried, wouldn't - I still don't know why since the PowerShell Docs are of desirable quality (and full of inconsistency...)

To import all modules on startup, I added the following. This produced some stderr output by powershell that couldnt be put to rest by `ErrorAction` or redirection without using the wrapping...

If anyone could elaborate on why's that would be very appreciated.

```
 # import installed modules on launch 
 $PsMods = $(Get-InstalledModule); 
 $($PsMods.forEach({ Import-Module -Name $_.Name -ErrorAction Ignore })) *> /dev/null
```