# Trying to Remotely use PsTools (PsExec) to Return a Result on Powershell

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am trying to run a script remotely that will double check that the IP address is correct using PsExec in Powershell. The problem is I only want it to return the result True or False and not show any other lines within  Powershell.

I have tried running background jobs as well but have not seemed to get that working, as when I do that it simply gives me nothing.

```
function remoteIPTest($Computer) {

    $result = & cmd /c PsExec64.exe \\$Computer -s cmd /c "ipconfig"

        if ($result -like "*10.218.5.202*") {
            return "True"
        }   
}

$Computer = "MUC-1800035974"
remoteIPTest $Computer
```

After running this, I just want the application to give return:

```
True
```

Instead of returning:

```
Starting cmd on MUC-1800035974... MUC-1800035974...
cmd exited on MUC-1800035974 with error code 0.
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psexec` prints its status messages to *stderr*, which a variable assignment such as `$result =` does *not* capture, so these messages still print to the screen.

Variable assignments only capture *stdout* output from external programs such as `psexec`, which in this case is `ipconfig`'s output.

Therefore, the answer is to *suppress stderr*, which you can do with `2>$null` (`2` is the number of PowerShell's error stream, which stderr maps to) - see [Redirecting Error/Output to NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881174/redirecting-output-to-null-in-powershell-but-ensuring-the-variable-remains-set).
Do note that this will also suppress true error messages.

In addition, the `cmd /c` calls are not needed, because you can use `psexec` to invoke other programs directly, if you have the path configured properly.

**Instead of this:**

```
$result = & cmd /c PsExec64.exe \\$Computer -s cmd /c "ipconfig"
```

**Do This:**

```
$result = PsExec64.exe \\$Computer -s ipconfig 2>$null
```

Hope it helps.