# Does 2>$null still work in Powershell 5.1?

Tags: powershell-5.1

It was my understanding that anything that writes to $error should be re-directable to $null, but I can't make it work, even with something as simple as substring or a bad cmdlet name:

[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKtGd.png)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> asdf 2>$null
asdf : The term 'asdf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...
```

All of the examples here do not seem to work:
[Redirecting output to $null in PowerShell, but ensuring the variable remains set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881174/redirecting-output-to-null-in-powershell-but-ensuring-the-variable-remains-set)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $qwerty = "a"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $qwerty.substring(0,2) 2>$NULL
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length...
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $qwerty.substring(0,2) | out-null
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length...
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that it might work but you need to pass it to an existing program as a parameter, otherwise it assumes that the executable is named "asdf" and not the variables of "asdf" being passed to it.  

Such as you are trying to run asdf.exe so it just fails ..
and you want it to run something like dir /asdf or something like that for this to work.  Now forgive me if I am wrong but I think this should at least get you onto the right track.

Comment: It's the powershell response that I'm trying to redirect out to null, rather than the target process or cmdlet. I'll give another example with a powershell function:


`$blah.substring(0,2) 2>$null 
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must... etc.`



The error message is still outputting to the console rather than to the $NULL variable

Comment: `get-command asdf 2>$null`

Comment: `get-command $blah.substring(0,2) 2>$null
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length...`  Didn't work